# How do I use the `nextLink` property of a result?

Tags: google-api-php-client

A query result object returns with `nextLink` set either to a URL for the next page of results as a string or a null, depending on whether there's another page after the current one. The docs are quite clear about this, but there's nothing in them about how to take that link and make another request for the next page.

I've been digging through the source and have only found that it appears as if there really isn't any way to make use of this value as anything other than a boolean telling me that there's more. To leave such an obviously loose end, even in a beta API, just doesn't sound like Google, so I must be missing something somehow.

The way my code is set up, I can't just reuse the request data that generated the initial request. I have separate logic to make the initial request and to parse the result-set into a usable form. That, and knowing that link is exposed as if it's meant to be used hints that there's a cleaner way than to modify the initial request. Just, how do I do that?

Comment: I think you might be looking at the contacts API specifically. You may wish to attempt to curl that new link to see if you get results. I was looking over that recently. I also think that there might be a getNext() call on the Object.

Comment: It's the Analytics API, actually. This code should be common across their different services, since `Google_Service_Analytics_DataGa_Resource` inherits just about everything `Google_Service_Resource`. The only functions are `get` (on the GA object) and `call` (on the superclass). `get` just sets up some arguments for `call` and then calls it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that seems to work. The important bit is at the bottom, where I take `nextLink` and use the pieces to make a fresh query. It isn't ideal, but it works better than trying to cURL things manually, as everything else online seems to suggest. `Google_Service_Analytics_GaData` will, of course, vary by which service is being used.

```
do {
    $rows = $results->getRows();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $record = array();

        foreach ($row as $i => $field) {
            $name = $headers[$i]->name;

            switch($headers[$i]->dataType) {
                case 'FLOAT':
                    $record[$name] = (float) $field;
                    break;
                case 'INTEGER':
                    $record[$name] = (int) $field;
                    break;
                default:
                    $record[$name] = (string) $field;
            }
        }

        $records[] = $record;
    };

    $nextLink = $results->getNextLink();

    if ($nextLink) {
        /* The GA API doesn't have anything to actually USE The link
         * they so helpfully supply, so we have to disassemble it and
         * make a new query off of it. Internally, 
         * $this->gaService->data_ga calls $this->gaService->call.
         * These are on `Google_Service_Analytics_DataGa_Resource` and
         * `Google_Service_Resource`, respectively.
         */
        $options = [];
        parse_str(substr($nextLink, strpos($nextLink, '?') + 1), $options);

        $results = $this->gaService->data_ga->call('get', [$options], "Google_Service_Analytics_GaData");
    }
} while ($nextLink);
```